# Traversing the Ledger

Tags: corda

I have a cordapp set up that uploads an attachment with each transaction. The attachment is a zipped file of a list of unique identifiers related to the tx. I am trying to implement logic that forbids the same unique identifier to appear again in a subsequent transaction. Let's say I have an initial tx with an attachment listing A,B,C,D,E and it passes. Then I have Tx 2a with attachment F,G,H and Tx 2b with attachment C,F,G,H. I would want 2a to be accepted but 2b to be rejected.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to store and query the history of identifiers. I know that the attachment will be saved to the tx history, but traversing the ledger and opening/reading all attachments to ensure there are no duplicates seems extremely intensive as we scale (the attachments are more likely to list thousands of unique identifiers rather than 5).

Is it practical to create a table on the db - perhaps even the off-ledger portion of the vault - that just contains all of the ids that have been used? The node responsible for checking redundancy could read the incoming attachment, query the table, check redundancy, sign the tx, and then insert the new ids into the table? Or is there something better we can do that involves actually traversing the ledger?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are not millions of identifiers and if you don't mind all of the past identifiers being in the current version of the state then you can accumulate them inside the state, inside a `Set`? The `Set` will ensure there are no dupes. The benefit of this approach is that you can then perform the checking logic inside the contract.

If you don't care about performing these checks inside the contract then you can do one of the approaches you suggested:

- "traversing the ledger" is really just performing a bunch of inefficient database queries queries as you rightly note
- the other approach you suggested seems like a good idea. Keep an off-ledger DB table with the identifiers in. Currently working on a feature to make this much easier. In the meantime you can use `ServiceHub.jdbcConnection` to execute queries against the DB.

Which one you choose really depends on other aspects of your use-case.

One thing you could try is maintain a bloom filter inside your state object. This way you get a space efficient data structure and quick set membership checks. You'll have to update the filter each time an identifier is added. Could be something to look at.

Cheers